# Using the android MediaStore from an Xamarin.Forms PCL project

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, mediastore

Does anyone know a way of accessing the Android MediaStore from an Xamarin.Forms PCL project?

I am trying to move a file into the public Download folder on Android, but since Android 11 scoped storage is required and I am not sure how to implement this in Xamarin.Forms.

I suspect that I might need to create a dependency service and call the native Android functions.

**EDIT**
Here is what I have attempted in the dependency service:

```
public void InsertIntoMediaStore(string filePath, string fileName) {

        string fileNameWithoutExt = Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, null);

        int fileSize = (int)new FileInfo(filePath).Length;
        byte[] buffer = null;

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        ContentResolver contentResolver = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.AppContext.ContentResolver;

        var appName = "TestApplication";

        values.Put(Android.Provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns.Title, fileNameWithoutExt);
        values.Put(Android.Provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns.MimeType, "image/jpg");
        values.Put(Android.Provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns.Size, fileSize);
        values.Put(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Downloads.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName, fileNameWithoutExt);

        Android.Net.Uri newUri = contentResolver.Insert(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Downloads.ExternalContentUri, values);

        System.IO.Stream save;

        try {
            buffer = new byte[1024];
            save = contentResolver.OpenOutputStream(newUri);

            Android.Content.Res.AssetManager assets = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.Assets;
            Android.Content.Res.AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.OpenFd(fileName);
            System.IO.Stream inputstream = descriptor.CreateInputStream();

            CopyFile(inputstream, save);
        }

        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        }
    }
```

Comment: "I might need to create a dependency service" - this is the answer

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Do you happen to know where I might find an example?

Comment: this is well documented on the Xamarin site, including samples.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. I know how to create the dependency service, I am just having trouble getting it to save my jpg file into the public Downloads folder. I have added the code that I am currently using in the dependency service.

Comment: I believe you need to use DownloadManager to write to the public downloads folder

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have permission to access the downloads folder:

```
    public async Task<bool> CheckStorageAsync()
    {
        PermissionStatus stat = (PermissionStatus)await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
        return (stat == PermissionStatus.Granted || stat == PermissionStatus.Restricted);
    }
```

These additional manifest permissions usually ease the way:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This is how it is used:

```
    private string getDownloadsFolder(string yourfilename)
    {
        if (CheckStorageAsync().Result) 
        {
            return = Path.Combine("/storage/emulated/0/Download", yourfilename);
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Then use StreamReader to read the file, or StreamWriter to write it.

```
    using var infile = new StreamReader(filepath);
    string instring = infile.ReadToEnd();
```